# Change the visibility of a view of a pressed item in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

I do the processing of click in the Activity.

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
            final RecyclerView avaRecycler = (RecyclerView) view2.findViewById(R.id.ava_recycler);
            avaRecycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(PersonEditActivity.this, 3));
            avaRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
            final AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter avaChooseRecyclerAdapter = new AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter(PersonEditActivity.this, new AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter.AvaViewHolder.MyClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAvaClickListener(int position) {
                    Toast.makeText(view2.getContext(), "Выбрана ава " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    chosenId = (int) avaRecycler.getAdapter().getItemId(position);
                    avaRecycler.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(position);
                }
            });
            avaRecycler.setAdapter(avaChooseRecyclerAdapter);
```

Layout of the item

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/ava_item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ava_item_imageview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/avatars_man" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ava_badge_yes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|right"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/ava_item_imageview"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ava_item_imageview"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/avatars_yes" />
```

I can not figure out how to change the visibility of ava_badge_yes by clicking on ava_item_imageview.

Edit.
My Adapter for recyclerview

```
    public class AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter.AvaViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "AvaChooseAdapter";
    Context context;
    private AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter.AvaViewHolder.MyClickListener myClickListener;

    List<Integer> resourceIds = Arrays.asList(
            R.drawable.avatars_01, R.drawable.avatars_02, R.drawable.avatars_03,
            R.drawable.avatars_04, R.drawable.avatars_05, R.drawable.avatars_06,
            R.drawable.avatars_07, R.drawable.avatars_08, R.drawable.avatars_09,
            R.drawable.avatars_10, R.drawable.avatars_11, R.drawable.avatars_12,
            R.drawable.avatars_13, R.drawable.avatars_14, R.drawable.avatars_15,
            R.drawable.avatars_16, R.drawable.avatars_17, R.drawable.avatars_18,
            R.drawable.avatars_19, R.drawable.avatars_20, R.drawable.avatars_21,
            R.drawable.avatars_22, R.drawable.avatars_23, R.drawable.avatars_24,
            R.drawable.avatars_25, R.drawable.avatars_26, R.drawable.avatars_27,
            R.drawable.avatars_28, R.drawable.avatars_29, R.drawable.avatars_30,
            R.drawable.avatars_31, R.drawable.avatars_32, R.drawable.avatars_33,
            R.drawable.avatars_34, R.drawable.avatars_35, R.drawable.avatars_36,
            R.drawable.avatars_37, R.drawable.avatars_38, R.drawable.avatars_39,
            R.drawable.avatars_40, R.drawable.avatars_41, R.drawable.avatars_42,
            R.drawable.avatars_43, R.drawable.avatars_44, R.drawable.avatars_45,
            R.drawable.avatars_46, R.drawable.avatars_47, R.drawable.avatars_48,
            R.drawable.avatars_49, R.drawable.avatars_50, R.drawable.avatars_51,
            R.drawable.avatars_52, R.drawable.avatars_53, R.drawable.avatars_54,
            R.drawable.avatars_55, R.drawable.avatars_56, R.drawable.avatars_57,
            R.drawable.avatars_58, R.drawable.avatars_59, R.drawable.avatars_60,
            R.drawable.avatars_61, R.drawable.avatars_62, R.drawable.avatars_63,
            R.drawable.avatars_64, R.drawable.avatars_65, R.drawable.avatars_66);

    public AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter(Context context, AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter.AvaViewHolder.MyClickListener m) {
        this.context = context;
        myClickListener = m;
    }

    public static class AvaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        protected MyClickListener myClickListener;
        protected ImageView iv;

        public AvaViewHolder(View itemView, MyClickListener myClickListener) {
            super(itemView);
            this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
            iv = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ava_item_imageview);
            iv.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (myClickListener != null) myClickListener.onAvaClickListener(getLayoutPosition());
        }

        public interface MyClickListener {
            void onAvaClickListener(int position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return resourceIds.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter.AvaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ava_item, parent, false);
        v.setPadding(14, 14, 14, 14);
        return new AvaViewHolder(v, myClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AvaViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.iv.setImageResource(resourceIds.get(position));
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder position: " + position + " | " + holder.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return resourceIds.size();
    }

    public getItem(int position){


    }
}
```

And i want to understand. 
On the forums write 3 options for processing clicks in the recyclerview
1. in ViewHolder
2. in OnBindViewHolder
3. With the use of the interface and the transfer of click processing in the activity. (I used this option)
But I don't understand the principle of choosing the place of treatment of pressing. In which cases to choose this or that method?
I would be very grateful if you explain. Highly.

Comment: please paste the adapter code, u should use onBindViewHolder, where u can get click even, according to items & able to change it

Comment: @Adnanul i added my adapter to question. look please.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the **onclick** in **Adapter** & see if , click item change the color

```
          @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (myClickListener != null) myClickListener.onAvaClickListener(getLayoutPosition());
AvaViewHolder.iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(100, 100, 50));
    }
}
```

Comment: i need by clicking on iv change visibility of other imageview at the same item

Comment: first tell me, if it change the clicked image background color. has it?

Comment: iv is red because of   Non-static field 'iv' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: iv.setOnClickListener(this); remove this line  and cut my onClick code into here " public static class AvaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener " . Now, tell me, if it works

Comment: it has the same result. Here is screenshot https://hdd.tomsk.ru/gallery/lvippdrx#nrbanaqg

Comment: AvaViewHolder.iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                log.e("Pos",position);
            }
        });

Comment: And comment everything in onClick. tell me the result, plz

Comment: do you think this code must be instead AvaViewHolder.iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(100, 100, 50)); ? If you do, i have the same result - 'iv' is red.

Comment: I mean , do exactly, what I say & see the result in log, if u clicked an image in recyclerview & get the position in logcat, let me know, plz

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html plz, try this as reference

Comment: it does not helped to me. I'm still searching the desicion